# Google maps are not being displayed in the screen using React

Tags: google-maps, reactjs

I am creating a component that renders a map, with the API of Google maps, it is not giving errors but it's not displaying the maps I don't know why.

Here  is my component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class GoogleMap extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){
        new window.google.maps.Map(this.refs.map, {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 11

        })
    }
    render(){
        return <div ref="map"/> 
    }
}
```

And here is where I call this component:

```
renderRents(rentsData){        
        return(
            <tr key={rentsData.id}>

               <td>
                   {rentsData.id}
               </td>
               <td>
                    <GoogleMap lon={rentsData.location.lon} lat={rentsData.location.lat}/>
               </td>
               <td>
                    {rentsData.status}
               </td>
               <td>
                    {rentsData.cost}
               </td>
           </tr>
        )
    }
```

Also, this is my script in index.html:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Note: My project is bootstrapped with `create-react-app`

Comment: I think you must specify a width & height for the map to display

Comment: What @AshKander said. Plus, take a look at [this](https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-react) or [this](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps) for smooth Google Map integration in React. Depending on your use case, I suggest you to pick one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register at google maps to get a api key. Then you basically provide that key while loading the google maps library as follows:

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=123123XXXXXX&sensor=false"
```

Check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=cs) for detailed steps on how to register.